# JSON Date Explanation

Tags: php, objective-c, json, mongodb

So, I'm a little bit confused by what I'm looking at. I'm converting a MongoDate to JSON using PHP's `json_encode` function and built-in MongoDB stuff. The result is this within my JSON string that's returned:

```
"date":{"sec":1344724737,"usec":0}}
```

I understand the `sec` value is UNIX epoch time (seconds from 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970 to be more precise). However, I don't know what the `usec` value is. Is it an unsigned integer value for the milliseconds? Should I be using `sec` to get the value? For the record, I'm converting this into an `NSDate` in an iOS application. It works that way, but I just like to know more about what these values are to make sure I am using the right one (and so I can sleep at night once it goes into production).

Comment: Not *milliseconds* from 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970; rather *seconds* from ...

Comment: @MajidFouladpour updated. That wouldn't be very many milliseconds ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an integer corresponding to the number of microseconds (μsec). You divide by 1000000 and add it to the `sec` value to get the full timestamp.

Comment: Accepted yours because it came first. That makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`usec` means `µseconds`, or microseconds. There are 1,000,000 microseconds in a second.